# Cambiar backgroundColor de un UIButton al pulsarlo

Tags: swift, swift4

Tengo el siguiente problema: Genero dinámicamente una serie de preguntas con dos respuestas (botones Sí y No). El número de preguntas (cuestionesCC) puede variar. Es un array que a veces tiene un número de elementos y otras veces, otro diferente.

Bien, esto funciona sin problemas.

Lo que yo pretendo es que un usuario al pulsar sobre un botón (Sí o No), éste quede marcado del alguna manera. Por ejemplo, cambiando el color del fondo o algo así. Sin embargo, en mi código, si pulso el botón, me lleva a la función buttonActionYesNo() y sólo ejecuta el print. Si lo vuelvo a pulsar, entonces ya si me cambia el color del fondo. Es decir, necesito dos toques para que cambie el color. Sin embargo, con un sólo toque sí me lee el print.

No sé qué lógica puede tener esto o dónde me estoy equivocando.

Este es el resumen de mi código.

```
for (index, cue) in cuestionesCC.enumerated(){
    let buttonYes = UIButton()
    buttonYes.backgroundColor = .green
    buttonYes.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10) // Add padding around text
    buttonYes.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    buttonYes.tag = 1
    buttonYes.setTitle("Yes", for: .normal)
    buttonYes.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionYesNo), for: .touchUpInside)

    let buttonNo = UIButton()
    buttonNo.backgroundColor = .red
    buttonNo.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10) // Add padding around text
    buttonNo.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    buttonNo.tag = 2
    buttonNo.setTitle("No", for: .normal)
    buttonNo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionYesNo), for: .touchUpInside)

    stackViewH.addArrangedSubview(buttonYes)
    stackViewH.addArrangedSubview(buttonNo)
}

@objc func buttonActionYesNo(sender: UIButton!) {
    print (sender.tag)  //funciona con un solo toque
    sender.backgroundColor = .gray  //solo funciona si tocas dos veces
    print ("entra")  //también funciona con un toque

}
```

¿Alguna orientación sobre qué está fallando? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Sigues teniendo el problema? He probado tu código y no tengo ese problema.

Comment: Gracias por responder. El problema persiste. No he encontrado solución. Por ahí he leído que puede ser un problema con el emulador del xcode, pero que la aplicación en un dispositivo real debería funcionar. Lo malo es que aún no he podido probarla sobre un iPhone real, así que no sé si funcionará o no. Aunque si a ti te funciona bien, imagino que sí que será un bug del xcode. Otra explicación no le encuentro.

Comment: Yo lo he probado en simulador. Siento no poder ayudarte.

Comment: Una curiosidad, ¿qué versión de xcode utilizas? Porque a mi con la versión 10.1 no me termina de funcionar bien esa parte. Gracias!

Comment: Utilizo la versión 11.0

Comment: Gracias, eso me ayuda bastante. Voy a actualizarme ahora mismo porque creo que por ahí me viene el fallo.

Answer (score 0):

El propio boton tiene elementos para poder estar en diferentes estados, puedes colocar el titulo con:

```
button.setTitle("Yes", for: .normal)
button.setTitle("No", for: .selected)
```

Después puedes colocar una imagen de fondo igual para ambos estados, como el botón no cuenta con una propiedad para color podemos crear una imagen apartir de un color como se puede ver a continuación:

```
public extension UIImage {
  public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
  }
}
```

Y despues con el color selected:

```
let selectedColorImage = UIImage(color: UIColor.green)
let unselectedColorImage = UIImage(color: UIColor.red)
button.setBackgroundImage(selectedColorImage, forState: .normal)
button.setBackgroundImage(unselectedColorImage, forState: .selected)
```

ya por ultimo solo tendrias que colocar algo que cambie su estado, como puede ser en el IBAction del boton

```
@objc func buttonActionYesNo(sender: UIButton!) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```